# ServiceStack.SSE: How do I get an instance o IServerEvents?

Tags: servicestack

I have the SSE plugin running in ServiceStack, and it works to access for example `/event-stream` etc.

Now, let's assume there are subscribers, but otherwise no action from outside. Suddenly, the server decides "I need to push this information to channel X". How do I do that? I seem to need in instance of `IServerEvents`, but I don't know where I get that instance.

I see it's injected into different `Service` implementations, but in this case, there is no service called, so I need to get this IServerEvents elsewhere. Let's assume an event is trigged, that fires a method inside the `AppSelfHostBase` implementation, so `OnObjectChange(...)` is triggered.

How do I then push some data out to a channel/subscriber in the `OnObjectChanged` method? Where do I get the `IServerEvents`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this code works almost anywhere:

`IServerEvents test = TryResolve<IServerEvents>();`

The IServerEvents instance will be returned and seems to function.

Comment: @mythz When does `IServerEvents test = TryResolve<IServerEvents>();` return an instance? When I try it now, it doent always return anything, its null sometimes, for example when I try to run it in the `override void Configure(...)`?